# How to apply custom CSS in material table in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Hi I am trying to apply custom CSS over material table but It is not working properly.
I tried to do that using makeStyles function in material UI but still it's not working. I want the sorting arrow right after the text. Right now sorting arrow is coming left to the text. I also want both arrow together up arrow and down arrow together. 
 I have created a function -

```
const useStylesTableSort = makeStyles({
  root: {
    flexDirection: "unset",
  },
});
```

This is my material table code -

```
<MaterialTable
  className={{useStylesTableSort.root}}
  style={{ flexDirection: "unset" }}
  title=""
/>
```

I want to add this function using className in material table but material table does not support className. style tag also not working. So how can I achieve this ? I want to change root css of MuiTableSortLabel. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you refer https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/sorting ?

Comment: for styling please refer https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/styling

Answer (score 5):

You can override the Container component and add a className to the `<Paper/>`, this is the main container of the Material-table.

```
 <MaterialTable
   columns={[]}
   data={data}
   components={{
    Container: (props) => <Paper className={classes.filterTable} {...props}/>
        }}
  />
```

Another way is to use the Style property.

```
<MaterialTable
   columns={[]}
   data={data}
   style={{
   marginTop:'50px'
     }}
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const styles = {
 materialStyle: {
    flexDirection: "unset" 
    }
  }
};

function Table(props) {
  return (
<MaterialTable
className={props.classes.materialStyle}
    />
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Table);
```

You can also refer on the this link: [Add Styling on Material-UI](https://codex.happyfuncorp.com/styling-and-theming-with-material-ui-react-material-design-3ba2d2f0ef25)

Comment: No we can't use className in material table.

Comment: className not supported from material-table. This is a wrong answer.

Comment: className is not supported from material-table. This is not useful answer